# AWS iOS SDK: Sending Email via AWSSES

Tags: ios, objective-c, aws-sdk

Does anyone have any experience using the latest Amazon AWS SDK 2.3.6 for sending an email via SES SMTP? I currently have an api key, secret, and smtp_url.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured it out. I confess Amazon's documentation is a little dense. Hope this helps someone else!

```
AWSSESSendEmailRequest *awsSESSendEmailRequest = [AWSSESSendEmailRequest new];
awsSESSendEmailRequest.source = @"source@email";
AWSSESDestination *awsSESDestination = [AWSSESDestination new];
awsSESDestination.toAddresses = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"to@email",nil];
awsSESSendEmailRequest.destination = awsSESDestination;

AWSSESMessage *awsSESMessage = [AWSSESMessage new];
AWSSESContent *awsSESSubject = [AWSSESContent new];
awsSESSubject.data = @"Subject goes here";
awsSESSubject.charset = @"UTF-8";

awsSESMessage.subject = awsSESSubject;
AWSSESContent *awsSESContent = [AWSSESContent new];
awsSESContent.data = @"Message goes here";
awsSESContent.charset = @"UTF-8";

AWSSESBody *awsSESBody = [AWSSESBody new];
awsSESBody.text = awsSESContent;
awsSESMessage.body = awsSESBody;
awsSESSendEmailRequest.message = awsSESMessage;


AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"ACCESS-KEY"
                                                                                                  secretKey:@"SECRET-KEY"];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSWest2
                                                                     credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

[[AWSSES defaultSES] sendEmail:awsSESSendEmailRequest completionHandler:^(AWSSESSendEmailResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error)
    {
        // error
    }
    else
    {
        // success
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the above code. I have another requirement which need to send the file through AWS SES.  I got to know that have to use the sendRawEmail API for the same. Can any one help with sample code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet of Send email in Swift 3.0 below.

```
    let serviceRegionType = AWSRegionType.usEast1
    let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider.init(accessKey: "access", secretKey: "secret")
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: serviceRegionType, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    let subject = AWSSESContent()
    subject?.data = "Subject"
    subject?.charset = "UTF-8"

    let messageBody = AWSSESContent()
    messageBody?.data = "Sample Message body"
    messageBody?.charset = "UTF-8"

    let body = AWSSESBody()
    body?.text = messageBody

    let theMessage = AWSSESMessage()
    theMessage?.subject = subject
    theMessage?.body = body

    let destination = AWSSESDestination()
    destination?.toAddresses = ["toaddress"]

    let send = AWSSESSendEmailRequest()
    send?.source = "source mail"
    send?.destination = destination
    send?.message = theMessage

    AWSSES.default().sendEmail(send!) { (response:AWSSESSendEmailResponse?, mailError: Error?) in
        print(mailError?.localizedDescription)
        if ((response?.messageId) != nil) {
            print("Mail has delivered succesfully")
        } else {
            print("Mail has failed to delivered")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to unicornherder's answer: your code worked well for my iOS app. However, because my app users are authenticated by Cognito, I did not need your code used to set up AWSStaticCredentialsProvider. This already happens in my AppDelegate per the sample code.

I *did* need to give my Cognito-authorized users permission to use SES, however. This last step is accomplished by adding the permission to the authUser role.